# The primitive type int of R.layout.main does not have a field out

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android, When I run the app it throws the following:

"The primitive type int of R.layout.main does not have a field out"

What am I doing wrong?

TIA
Ricard

Comment: Please post your main.xml here so we can check it for errors.

Comment: Do you have an R.layout.main.out somewhere?

Comment: Have you defined a variable R?

http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/dab177f7909e1810

Comment: @Mur Votema your question doesn't make any sense.  The R file is automatically created when you compile the android project.

Comment: Thanks, it was a syntax error on my part.

Comment: @Mayra but it cann't stop you to create a variable with name R to get an error .. I'd like to write a private message, but don't know how :)

Comment: @Mur Votema Oh, I see, I misunderstood what you were saying..I would never name a variable R, so I didn't think of it as a possibility!

Answer (score 3):

1) The 'R' file is generated from the assets in the res folder.

2) Check the file /res/layout/main.xml.  The error message is stating there is not an 'out' field in this file. So your Java code must align with main.xml.

3) Check the 'R' file generated by the build process.  Verify there is a 'main' in the 'layout' class.

Hints Eclipse does a good job of building the 'R' file.  If it does not match the 'res' folder rebuild the project.

Do not edit the 'R' file by hand as it will be overwritten during the next build.

Comment: Thanks All, I got it working, it looks like setContentView(R.layout.main); was the problem, I originally had it as
R.layout.main.out